# How can I avoid that the configuration of the provided debian image for beagle bone black will hinder load of gadget drivers?

Tags: debian, beagleboneblack

I used an given ArchLinux on a BeagleBone Black and used on test environment the gadget drivers(g_printer, g_serial) as I encounter driver problems with some wifi dongles. The drivers where not compatible with 4.19 of linux.

After some hassle I moved to a a raspberry pi 3+ and like that the provided debian image was more usable in this context.

Now i tried to use this image also for the other test but encounter following message

```
sudo modprobe g_printer
dmesg | tail
```

> [  321.445928] udc-core: couldn't find an available UDC - added [printer] to list of pending drivers

I tried to unload all the modules with also

```
sudo modprobe -rf g_ether
sudo modprobe -rf usb_f_mass_storage
```

But they where already used from the debian image to provide easy-to-use interfaces. I didn't find a way to unload all of those.

I needed to change something with the boot up. But where and how I can find the scripts and change them to avoid the load?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can start a search where the usb0 interface is loaded or which driver is used in every file by searching recursively in every file.

`sudo grep -r "usb0" /`

follow the input, if it is slow enough you will see some scripts in /opt/scripts/boot/. The grep will crash in the end.

```
debian@beaglebone:~$ ls /opt/scripts/boot/
am335x_evm.sh           autoconfigure_usb1.sh  capemgr.sh  generic.sh          legacy           omap5_uevm.sh
autoconfigure_usb0.sh~  beagle_x15.sh          default     generic-startup.sh  omap3_beagle.sh
debian@beaglebone:~$
```

As you can see I wanted to avoid loading of autoconfigure_usb0.sh by adding a '~' to it. But that didn't helped. The interface where already generated and the driver loaded.

So instead to manipulate the g_multi driver to parallel load the driver by using the configfs I decided to edit the am335x_evm.sh.

I added following line

```
USB_NETWORK_DISABLED="yes"
USB_IMAGE_FILE_DISABLED="yes"
```

but that didn't avoid the loading within the ifs. Actually I don't understand why but i guessed the environment variables are interpreted at start of the script or i don't set the right values to trigger following ifs

```
if [ ! "x${USB_NETWORK_DISABLED}" = "xyes" ]; then
```

So i moved the file by using

```
mv /opt/scripts/boot/am335x_evm.sh /opt/scripts/boot/am335x_evm.sh~
```

and restarted the system with

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

Well and see I can use gadget driver g_printer.

Following links helped me. Everyone that hassle to much with the beagle bone should at least stay some hours in the beagle chat room [Chat group around the beagle bone](https://beagleboard.org/chat)

They pointed again to the /opt/scripts/boot/ folder and different ways to dynamically load multiple drivers [Drivers to load multiple driver instances](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/usb/gadget_multi.txt) and the provided interfaces [Kernel USB Gadget Configfs Interface](https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/slides/USB%20Gadget%20Configfs%20API_0.pdf).

[How do I grep recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1987928/92938) helped.